# Best way to make a counter based on time

Tags: python, algorithm

How can we increment a global variable every 2 seconds without using threads?

```
def get_interval():
    var a=1;
    for every 2 second
    a++;
    return a;
```

How can I increment the value of `a` every 2 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you never access the variable, then even if it increased over time it wouldn't be very useful.  So what you really want is something you can access in some way which will give you an answer as if it *were* increasing over time.  But to do that, all you need to do is subtract the current time from when you started.

For example, you could use something like this:

```
import time

def make_ticker():
    start = time.time()
    def elapsed():
        now = time.time()
        return now-start
    return elapsed
```

And then after starting it off, all you need to do is write `a()` instead of `a`:

```
>>> a = make_ticker()
>>> a()
3.3126659393310547
>>> a()
5.144495010375977
>>> a()
7.766999006271362
```

Similarly, if you want to count the number of 2-second periods that have elapsed:

```
def make_ticker(seconds):
    start = time.time()
    def elapsed():
        now = time.time()
        return (now-start)//seconds
    return elapsed

>>> a = make_ticker(2)
>>> a()
0.0
>>> a()
1.0
>>> a()
1.0
>>> a()
2.0
```

(You can trivially modify to start at 1.)

Comment: Thanks DSM, it save my time

Answer (score 1):

If you're not worried about exact times, you can sleep for 2 seconds in between incrementing like this:

```
import time

a = 1

for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(2)
    print a
    a += 1
```

Output:

```
1
2
...
9
10
```

Comment: Actually i want output as  1, 2, 3, 4,... whenever we call the function.

Comment: Updated answer to show that